# Не правильная формула excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Вот два скрина: http://prntscr.com/bin23c - это сама формула, прикреплю еще код сюда.
Вот страница, где должна работать формула: http://prntscr.com/bin2ti

Если я подставляю данные в диапазон'Операции'!$A:$G , то таблица в любом случае = 0
В чем неправильность текущей формулы?

```
=iferror(QUERY('Операции'!$A:$G;"select SUM(E) where A >= date '2016-04-01' and A <= date '2016-04-31' and C = """&$A2&""" Label SUM(E) ''";);0)
```

Возможно есть аналоги подобной формулы?

Comment: Дополните вопрос, в чем неправильность текущей формулы?

Comment: @vikttur на самом деле этот вопрос был задан раньше, но у другого зато ответ есть. И в данном случае не "возможный", а чуть ли не "посимвольный" дубликат :)

Comment: Автор, возможно, потнрял свою тему и создал еще одну. Автор тот же, вопрос тот же. зачем хранить дубль?